# Bower does not install components

Tags: javascript, bower

I have been using `bower` locally to manage JavaScript dependencies for a project I am working on. Typically, everything works just fine.

However, today, I tried to start a new project using some code from previous projects. Namely, using the previous `component.json` and `.bowerrc` files:

```
// .bowerrc
{
  "directory": "src/static/js/lib"
}

//component.json
{
  "name": "backbone-project",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "dependencies": {
    "backbone": "~0.9.10",
    "underscore": "~1.4.3",
    "jasmine": "~1.3.1",
    "jasmine-jstd-adapter": "~1.1.2",
  }
}
```

However, when I try to run `bower install`, I just get a generic error:

```
± % bower install
bower error
```

I have run `mkdir -p src/static/js/lib` to ensure that the folders exist, and this works in other projects that I have done.

Why is it that bower isn't installing dependencies? How can I get more information about this error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `component.json` is invalid. Notice the dangling comma `"jasmine-jstd-adapter": "~1.1.2",`, which is not allowed in JSON.

Answer (score 1):

This silent death also happens if there is a blank version number.

See these related issues: [Using an invalid version value in bower.json silently fails](https://github.com/bower/bower/issues/439) and [bower install doesn't generate the components directory](https://github.com/bower/bower/issues/414).